# How to pass field name and value of dynamic form on submit php

Tags: php, forms, dynamic, field

I have a form that has fixed fields as well as dynamic fields created from a database.  the fields could be different every time and they are dropdowns with options like color size etc.I could name the dropdowns like this:

```
name="options[]"
```

and then do something like:

```
foreach($options as $option) {
//add to db
}
```

however that only gives me the values and I need to know the optionID as well

I could do somethign like:

```
name="<? echo $optionID; ?>"
```

for the dropdown but I don't know what optionID's were included in the form when I try to process the submitted data.  how do I pass both the optionID and it's selected value when adding fields to a form dynammically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the array multidimensional.  Something like this might work for you:

```
name="options[<?php echo $optionID;?>][]" 

foreach ($_POST['options'] as $ID) {
  foreach ($ID as $value) {
   // stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: @Michael I am getting `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\onlineExam\emq.php on line 9.` Can you help me with this?

Comment: @programmingArrow Does that line 9 point to where you have the equiv of `echo $optionID;` ? That would indicate the variable `$optionID` is an array and you either need to retrieve a specific value by index or you need to perform whatever you're doing in a loop.

Comment: No it's when I am trying to print the value of `$ID`, I can print the value of `$value`, but how do I get the corresponding id value?

Comment: @programmingArrow Oh, do you mean the _index_ value of `$value`?  That would be `foreach ($ID as $index => $value)` to access the iterating array key in `$index`.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBerkowski