# Forms with a variable number of fields

Tags: php

I'm attempting to create a sort of marketplace. Each item on the market has a type (i.e. the item being sold), a value, a quantity, a seller name, and an id, and all of this information is stored in a MySQL database.

When the user views the market, all entries in the market are returned. In addition, an input text field appears at the end of each entry. The user can enter any number between leaving it blank (0) and the max quantity available.

My problem is that since each input field is the result of a while loop of unknown iterations, I can't simply hard code a name into each field. I've tried using a counter variable to keep track and make names, but it doesn't seem to be working. For example: `name='.$i++.'`

On a related note, in order for the program to work, each field needs to send two values - the id (which I can use to look up the rest of the entry's values) and the quantity that the user wishes to purchase. I've been doing this with a hidden field before the input quantity field. I'm not sure if this is a good way of going about this, but I should note that there's no need as far as I can tell for the id to be kept secret.

Just so everything's clear, here's a basic UI mockup:
http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/2654/marketui.jpg

Note that the column starting with  consists of user inputted values (i.e. the 100s are the values of user-inputted text fields). The hitch is that while there are 2 rows in this example, the actual number is not deterministic, and so I can't hard code names for each input field.

Comment: I answered a very similar question earlier today. Long story short, use `name=[id][]` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628518/how-to-pass-field-name-and-value-of-dynamic-form-on-submit-php/6628613#6628613

Comment: @Michael: That doesn't look like valid PHP syntax to me.

Comment: @Michael: Ah, you mean an HTML name attribute of `"id[]"`, ie. `<input type="whatever" name="id[]" />`?

Comment: @Tomalak Name attribute as a 2D array: `name='something[id][]`. Not sure what I was writing up there.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

For the first problem, simple.  Do:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($returnedSQLarray); $i++) {
//your display code
....

....
echo("<input name='quantity-$i'>");
}
```

although I still am having trouble imagining why you can't use the product's ID in the quantity's name attribute somehow.  `for()` loops are great for this kind of looping, though, so if this really is the way you need to handle it you're covered.

The hidden input is fine.  Pretty standard, even.  Anyone who wants to can send your webserver whatever data they want, so you should only really care about serverside security anyway.

Comment: It's better to use parameter arrays. Far easier to iterate over in the target script. And what is this symbol `o`? Indentation?

Comment: The symbol o is me being profoundly unintelligent.  Fixed.  And yeah, my weapon of choice in this case would indeed be parameter arrays, but given his requirements I wanted to directly answer his specific difficulty regardless of whether his plan was the right way to do it.

Comment: @Tomalak, this may indeed be bad practice, but I find that the answers I appreciate most are the ones that tell me how to do the boneheaded thing I ask, not the ones that answer a different, more correct question.  I'm definitely more receptive to "This is how you do it, but you might not want to" and by that point JamWaffles had already covered that particular base.

Comment: I never said that it's bad practice. I said that there are easier ways. Perhaps my use of the word "better" was misleading, but my second sentence was quite clear.

Comment: Ah, it may have been me being unclear.  I was saying that answering the asked question instead of offering better solutions was potentially bad practice, not that you implied that my solution was bad practice.  Ignore me, I'm done causing accidental drama.  ;)

Comment: No worries. I veer between your viewpoint and the (more popular) opposite viewpoint, as written on my profile. I think it depends on context to a large degree. Sometimes it's not clear that the OP should really trust his/her own judgement yet, and sometimes it is.

Answer (score 11):

> My problem is that since each input
>   field is the result of a while loop of
>   unknown iterations, I can't simply
>   hard code a name into each field. I've
>   tried using a counter variable to keep
>   track and make names, but it doesn't
>   seem to be working.

Name your inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" name="myName[]" />
<input type="text" name="myName[]" />
<input type="text" name="myName[]" />
```

Then, in your PHP, `$_POST['myName']` or `$_GET['myName']` is an array.

This is documented [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).

---

> On a related note, in order for the
>   program to work, each field needs to
>   send two values - the id (which I can
>   use to look up the rest of the entry's
>   values) and the quantity that the user
>   wishes to purchase. I've been doing
>   this with a hidden field before the
>   input quantity field.

Sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on what @Michael has said in his comment, you need to turn the `name='id'` into an array, like this (PHP):

`echo '<input type="text" name="id[' . $i . ']">'`

Where `$i` is incremented every loop.

When the form is posted, you can access this array like this:

`$_POST['id']['1']`

Replacing `['1']` with whatever you want.