# add multiple textbox using button click in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hello I am  trying to add multiple textbox when click on button. i have write following HTML code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function addRow(btn) {         
     var parentRow = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
     var table = parentRow.parentNode;
     var rowCount = table.rows.length;
     var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
     var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
     var element1 = document.createElement("input");
     element1.type = "text";
     cell1.appendChild(element1);
     var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
 }
</script>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="data1" value="abc" /></td>
      <td><button type="button" onClick ="addRow(this)">Add</button></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

i dont know how to do . kindly tell me how to do this stuff .... thank you in advance

Comment: what is happening, any errors, is the function being called?  Can you check using firebug?

Comment: no i just try in wecschool may be function is not call

Comment: @kapil you want this http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/9EKRB/ or http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/9EKRB/1/ ??

Comment: @AjinderSingh i have already write like thiks onClick ="addRow(this)"

Comment: @TusharGupta woww... thats great

Comment: @TusharGupta i can ad text box but if i want to add drop down then? what to write instead of "txtbox"

Comment: It's working, you should add your script before table:[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EKfVv/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631786/forms-with-a-variable-number-of-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this sample...

```
var emails = document.getElementById('emails'),
 add_link = document.createElement('a'),
 template = emails.getElementsByTagName('div'),
 current = template.length,
 max = 20;
 template = template[0];

 submit1.onclick = function () {
 var new_field = template.cloneNode(true);
 current += 1;
 new_field.innerHTML = new_field.innerHTML.replace(/1/g, current);
 emails.appendChild(new_field);
if (current === max) {
    add_link.onclick = null;
    document.body.removeChild(add_link);
}
return false;
};

document.body.appendChild(add_link);
```

For demo http://jsfiddle.net/wQfLT/145/

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your JavaScript code in the head section.

[**DEMO of your code**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/9EKRB/3/)

same code with jQuery

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/9EKRB/)

```
var txtbox = '<td><input type="text"/></td>';

function addRow(btn) {
    $(btn).closest('tr').append(txtbox);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/9EKRB/1)

```
var txtbox = '<tr><td><input type="text"/></td></td>';

function addRow(btn) {
    $(btn).closest('table').append(txtbox);
}
```

References

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

To add Drop-down list

you just need to add dropdown list code in the `var txtbox`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/9EKRB/2)

```
var txtbox = '<tr><td><select><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option><option value="audi">Audi</option></select></td></td>';

function addRow(btn) {
    $(btn).closest('table').append(txtbox);
}
```

Comment: Hello i have use this in my page but it append end of the table .. i want to add after particular div. then tell me how to do