# i can add textbox with button but i don't know how to remove

Tags: javascript, html

```
    var emails = document.getElementById('emails'),
     add_link = document.createElement('a'),
     template = emails.getElementsByTagName('div'),
     current = template.length,
     max = 20;
     template = template[0];

     submit1.onclick = function () {
     var new_field = template.cloneNode(true);
     current += 1;
     new_field.innerHTML = new_field.innerHTML.replace(/1/g, current);
     emails.appendChild(new_field);
    if (current === max) {
        add_link.onclick = null;
        document.body.removeChild(add_link);
    }
    return false;
    };

document.body.appendChild(add_link);
```

copy from this link
[add multiple textbox using button click in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130697/add-multiple-textbox-using-button-click-in-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top)

how to create button for remove ,please tell me

Comment: https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=remove%20element%20from%20dom

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this.

```
elememt.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

This question has been asked and posted on this site.  Look at this link.
[Remove an Element with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933157/how-to-remove-an-html-element-using-javascript)